# Order Email Template: add information depending on payment method

Tags: magento2

I would like to insert an additional text in the order confirmation email if the selected payment method is "Bank Transfer Payment". How can I achieve this? Is there a way to use an if-condition or 'depend' in the template?

In the default template I found the variable "payment_html" (Payment Details). Where can I set/override this value for the payment method "Bank Transfer Payment"?

I am grateful for any advice!

**EDIT:**
In the meantime I found out that the value for the variable *payment_html* in case of the payment method *Bank Transfer Payment* is generated from the field *Configuration / Settings / Stores / Payment Methods / Bank Transfer Payment -> Instructions*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use depend like this :

```
{{depend condition}}

{{/depend}}
```

example : {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}

But the variable "payment_html" should display the method of payment by  default

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Nico2P. I found out where the value for payment_html can be set in this case and updated my question.